# Google Firebase HTTP Post

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to request POST for Google Firebase in server. I followed the document guideline, but it has not worked.

My sending message function is following thing.

```
private static void sendMsg() throws IOException 
{
    String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=XXXX");

    JSONObject msg=new JSONObject();
    msg.put("message","test8");

    JSONObject parent=new JSONObject();

    parent.put("to", "XXXXX");
    parent.put("data", msg);

    con.setDoOutput(true);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + parent.toString());
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode+" "+con.getResponseMessage());

}
```

The response code is "411" and the message is "Length Required". 
I also tried to set the content length, but the result was same.

Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have all the setup right but are not writing the data.  Add the statements shown:

```
con.setDoOutput(true);
// Added
OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
os.write(parent.toString());
os.flush();
os.close();
```